# When editing TextView on a modal it shows the underneath view blinking

Tags: ios7, uitextview

I had already came across with this same situation but the **scenario** here is:

1. I have presented a view controller with the modal style
   UIModalPresentationFullScreen
2. Right after I've shown another view controller with the modal style UIModalPresentationPageSheet
3. When the user starts editing the textview and taps the backspace button the view underneath starts blinking over the modal screen and the keyboard

Has anyone else come across this sort of bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been occurring for popOvers/UIAlertViews/Modals. 
I've resolved the problem by removing alpha of the views underneath.

For View under modals or popOvers I've removed the following code-snippets:

```
layer.shadowOpacity
view.alpha
```

For AlertView I've removed calls to shouldRasterize:
I had my own implementation of the AlertView so I've set it to NO;

```
layer.shouldRasterize
```